# Sending a message - read if seen programmatically

Tags: message, inbox, facebook-messages

Currently we run a booking service and we would like to give our members the option to install our app (soon to be app) and recieve booking information to facebook.

We already offer them booking information through email, SMS and regular mail.
Now we would also like to offer them this new method of receieveng their own booking information.

The question is, can you send a message from an app in facebook? Or in any other way send a message to the facebook inbox? (We are aware of the method to send regular mail to username@facebook.com.)

Also if there is a way to send a message, is there a way to read/access if seen?

Best regards,
Adam

Comment: Have you looked through the Facebook API and made any attempt to do this?  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/message/  It certainly appears to be possible, so I guess the answer to your question is simply "yes."  At least for the sending part.  It's not really clear what else you're asking about reading/accessing the message.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If you, as a person, send a message to another person. Let's say Person A sends message to Person B. When Person B views the message then it will be visible to Person A that Person B has seen the message. That was the other question, is it possible to know if Person B has "seen" the message through programming? I don't know if I am able to explain it better.